# Playstore upload of an application

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I have implemented inapp billing in  my android application. The application is working fine for test orders but while trying to buy the application actually from playstore it shows me the error message "Your transaction cannot be completed".
even the actual buying for subscription product is working fine. What might be the reason for above error?

Comment: capture logs and update them in your question

Comment: Just in case, remember that the purchase process will not work if you try to make the purchase from an application that has a version number bigger than the one that is currently published on Google Play.